# How to calculate sum of a formula field in crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

In some inherited code, I see group headers/footers have items like `'Sum of @numcount`' . I cannot get the sum of a formula field. Any thoughts?

Comment: When I do a Right click , insert sum, I dont see the formula field in the fields to summarize. Some how i can see them on the other machine. Looks like a version issue to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know what version of CR the reports were created in?  What version are you using on your machine?

Comment: 11.5.3700.0 on both. I see this is not taking me any where :(

Comment: Can you provide the formula you're trying to summarize?

Comment: Cost = items * 10 

I wanted to get the sum of cost (total cost).

Comment: you can use running total sum fields. @schar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only reason that I know of why a formula wouldn't be available to summarize on is if it didn't reference any database fields or whose value wasn't dynamic throughout sections of the report. For example, if you have a formula that returns a constant it won't be available. Or if it only references a field that is set throughout the report and returns a value based on that field, like "if {parameter}=1 then 1" would not be available either.

In general, the formula's value should not be static through the sections of the report you're summarizing over (Though the way Crystal determines this is beyond me and this doesn't seem to be a hard and fast rule)

EDIT: One other reason why a formula wouldn't be available is if you're already using a summary function in that formula. Only one level of summaries at a time!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at why it wont list my formulae. Now I got it. I removed the constant and it shows up.

Comment: +1, I didn't think about this initially, but I've encountered this behavior as well.

Answer (score 7):

*(Assuming you are looking at the reports in the Crystal Report Designer...)*

Your menu options might be a little different depending on the version of Crystal Reports you're using, but you can either:

- **Make a summary field:** Right-click on the desired formula field in your detail section and choose "Insert Summary".  Choose "sum" from the drop-down box and verify that the correct account grouping is selected, then click OK.  You will then have a simple sum field in your group footer section.
- **Make a running total field:** Click on the "Insert" menu and choose "Running Total Field..."***  Click on the New button and give your new running total field a name.  Choose your formula field under "Field to summarize" and choose "sum" under "Type of Summary".  Here you can also change when the total is evaluated and reset, leave these at their default if you're wanting a sum on each record. You can also use a formula to determine when a certain field should be counted in the total. (Evaluate: Use Formula)

Comment: When I look at Availble Tables and Fields to create sum or a running total, I donot see any of the formulae I have created.

Answer (score 2):

You Can simply Right Click Formula Fields- > new
Give it a name like TotalCount then Right this code:

```
if(isnull(sum(count({YOURCOLUMN})))) then
0
else
(sum(count({YOURCOLUMN})))
```

and Save then Drag and drop **TotalCount** this field in header/footer.
*After you open  the "count" bracket you can drop your column there from the above section.See the example in the Picture[image]*

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
Sum({Tablename.Columnname})
```

It will work without creating a summarize field in formulae.