# Is there any crystal report forumla to calculate VAT and Grand Total?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Can I calculate the VAT and Grand total from a column displayed in a crystal report ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, running totals and grand totals are parts of CR and you can use the designer to add them.

VAT calculation is a formula and surely you can include formulas.

refer to the CR documentation for how to add totals (Grand or running totals) and field based formulas.

check also online and here in SO: I have found this one, not exactly what you need but if you read question and all answers and comments you will get a feeling on how CR works, at least a starting point.

Heather's answer even guides you step by step on how to do things in the report designer ;-)

[How to calculate sum of a formula field in crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570322/how-to-calculate-sum-of-a-formula-field-in-crystal-reports)