# Unable to sort a group in Crystal Reports by another value

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, grouping

I'm working on a Crystal Reports-report (CR version 11.5) and I'm having big trouble sorting one of my groups.

I need to sort this group (part numbers) by the percentage of quality remarks on orders of that part. Parts with most quality remarks should be on top in the report.

The problem is that I only seem to be able to sort the Part Group by summary fields. And I don't seem to be able to put this percentage of quality remarks in a summary field.

This is, I think, because this percentage is calculated by taking a Count of remarks, divided by the total quantity delivered of that part. I think the problem is the Count, because readily available values from the Database of Formulas are available to summarize. But the percentage is not...

Is there a way around this? Because this report is not very useful if I can't sort it on the Parts with most remarks %...

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting your data? Can you not make a data view on your server that calculates this percentage and use that view as an additional data source? Having Crystal calculate things is generally only useful on a line-by-line basis. If you need it to calculate, summarize, and then sort? It's not really able to do that without some "hacking" of Crystal and it is time consuming. Letting the server calculate those percentages would be much faster, but if you don't have that sort of access, we'll have to work in Crystal.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant if you want to summarize then calculate then sort it cannot do that but if you want to calculate, summarize that calculation, and then sort, that you can do.

Comment: Hi @Ally, I could try and put everything on the DB in a stored procedure. I'll do that when I don't succeed the current way. Right now I'm just joining some tables straight from the DB into CR.

Comment: @Ally, I need to calculate, summarize and then sort. But it doesn't work due the to fact that in my calculation I use a 'Count'. I can summarize other DB fields and formula fields, no problem, but not the one I need. And the only difference seems to be that it uses a Count. Is there a way around this, or am I doomed?

Comment: Just read something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570322/how-to-calculate-sum-of-a-formula-field-in-crystal-reports  
*One other reason why a formula wouldn't be available is if you're already using a summary function in that formula. Only one level of summaries at a time!*  
I suppose the Count I use in the calculation is a summary function, and then trying to make a summary field (sum) based on that field doesn't work because it's a second summary...does that sound like what could be going on?

Comment: It's going to save you a lot of headache if you just create a View or Stored Procedure on your Database that calculates the percentage for you. If you're just wanting to show Percentage by Part Number, just output those two things as a table and set it as an additional data source in your report and join it to your part table so there would be a one-to-one relation. That way, you don't have repeating lines and you have your percentage. Your server is going to calculate things A LOT faster than Crystal could anyway. So, I think that's the way to go. Let me know if you need help setting it up.

Comment: Hi @Ally, thanks for the feedback. You know what? I wasn't aware of the fact that I could combine both a regular selection of tables in CR, and also use custom stored procedures and then even join them together! That's so great! Thanks! I do prefer for more complex stuff to just do everything on the server in a stored procedure, but reality is that I have a lot of reports here that I just can't rewrite in a hurry. So this combination is a nice third option! I'm going try your suggestions and I'll let you know how it works out!

Comment: Hi @Ally, just to follow up: I ended up rewriting the report in a stored procedure that gives me all info that I need in the report. This way I can easily sort the group that I wanted. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @Ally, how can I accept one of your comments as an answer? I'm not too familiar with this yet...